# How to use OwinStartup with WebAPI self host

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

Can anyone explain me about OwinStartup and how to use this in self hosted web api?

this is my current code in windows service:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            var config =
               new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:60065");
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() {

                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host your owin in a console application, let's say.
In this case you should do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string uri = "http://localhost:8080/";

        using (WebApp.Start(uri, Startup.Configuration))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started listening on " + uri);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Shutting down...");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the startup:

```
public class Startup
    {
    public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() 
        {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        }
}
```